# Selenium Chromedriver Doesn't Load Page

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to scrape a page using selenium and the problem im facing is that the page which the webdriver launched doesnt load the required url. Url was loaded into address, it tries to load but just stopped. I copied the url to a normal browser and it loaded straight away. The error message i got was

> [7020:13796:0309/161709.883:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(924)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -201

anyone can help? Im using python 3.7.1.

Comment: Have you tried to load other pages with selenium? Does it work correctly?

Comment: yes, my other scripts are working well. im thinking it could be the website, but i have no idea why and how to fix it.